# How to write yml file uploading flask app from github to iis server on aws ec2 windows instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, yaml, devops, github-actions

I want to upload a flask app. So I want to create a continuous integration from github actions using web deploy (github marketplace) and upload it to the IIS server which I configured on AWS ec2 windows instance.

```
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  deploy:

runs-on: windows-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Configure AWS Credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.MY_AWS_KEY_ID}}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
    aws-region: us-east-2
- name: GitHub Actions WebDeploy
  uses: cschleiden/webdeploy-action@v1
     webSiteName:'Default Web Site'

  with:
    path: |
          app.py
```

### Please ignore the identation for now .

I know the above yml file is wrong and thats what i wanted to find out what should i modify into it to make it work. Also how should i know IIS site name?

Please help me

Comment: I've fixed up your indentation, that might start you on the right track for YAML validity for GH Actions.

Comment: @jidicula it wasn't an identation issue, i just wanted to know how should i write yaml file to succesfully upload my app.py file on IIS server on aws ec2 windows instance

Comment: you could refer this link for writing yml file: [link1](https://github.com/watsonpeng/sample-python-flask/blob/master/appspec.yml) , [link2](https://github.com/ccdtzccdtz/Deploy-Flask-App-on-AWS-EC2-Instance/blob/master/Deploy%20Flask%20App%20on%20AWS%20EC2%20Instance.ipynb)